# Linq To Entity MVC

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have class which has ICollection of Images. I need to bring only single image from database:

var object=db.Context.Where(l=>l.Name=="John" &&
                               l.Images==l.Images.Single())

The query above is not correct. Can someone help how to return only single image from ICollection of Images?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the structure of your classes, but possibly something like this:

`var object = db.Context.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "John");`

or

`var object = db.Context.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "John").Images.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: My class is something like this: public class{public string name {get;set;} public virtual ICollection<Images> Image {get;set;}}. First, in filter action I am creating a new object by selecting only Images from class, then based on parameters i am doing filtering. Also, I have class Images which has Content, Filename. Where exactly do I need to apply FirstorDefault? During new object creation or during filtering? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
var object=db.Context.Where(l=>l.Name=="John").FirstOrDefault();
```

FirstOrDefault expects zero or more results and you only want the first item on the result.

Comment: Thanks. I will try

Comment: I think your code will give me the first or default item. My class is the following: public class
{
   public Name username {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Images> Image {get;set;}
},  I have class called Images which has Content type and filename. In my filter action, first I am creating new object by selecting only public virtual ICollection property of Images. But I want to return single Image either in new object creation or in WHERE clause where I start filtering based on parameters of controller. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try the next code:

```
var singleImage=db.Context.Where(n=>n.Name=="John").Select(m=>m.Images).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks. i will try it